# SmsRetrieverApi Not getting Otp

Tags: android, android-studio

I have integrated SmsRetrieverApi to automatically detect the OTP.

But I am getting an error
[SmsRetrieverApiChimeraService] No matching message is found.

Comment: Finally I got the Solution.

Comment: My Message Format is not correct. So that's Why I am getting that error.Message format should be like that. Please Follow https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify
To construct SMS Format

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/SmsVerifyCatcher) library which is really helpful for fetching sms

compile 'com.github.stfalcon:smsverifycatcher:0.3.1'

```js
if(Check yor permission) {

 smsVerifyCatcher = new SmsVerifyCatcher(this, new OnSmsCatchListener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onSmsCatch(String message) {
                String code = message.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                //Parse verification code

                myTextView.setValue(code + "");
                verify.performClick();

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use permission to receive the SMS message because I got the notification from Google Play that they will remove my app If I use 'SMS Recieve' Permission. that's why I used SMSRetrievr API to get the OTP automatically.